# Check a value within an array and reorder it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning JavaScript and I don't know how to do the following:

```
var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getDay();

    var days = ['Lunes','Martes','Miercoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sábado','Domingo'];
    var week = days.map((day, _id) =>

    function CheckDay(n) {
        for (i=0; i<days.length; i++) {
                if (n === days_id[i]-1){
                    days[i].position = 0;
                }else{
                i++;
                }
        }
    }
```

I just want to get the current date (the number of the day specifically, if it's Tuesday the number 2, for example), and compare it with my array which has 7 positions (each one for a day in the week). When it matches the number and the day in the array, I want to reorder the day within the array to the first position.

I am aware that the previous lines are more pseudo-code than code itself, but I wanted to transmit what I wanted to acquire.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it a homework?

Comment: Is it a pseudo-code?

Comment: You are looking for the [getDay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) function.

Comment: Nope, just practicing. And it's not pseudo-code but just an approximation of what I want.

Comment: I've used getDay in the first two lines (and it's the only thing that works), you can see it above.

Answer (score 1):

One way this could be done:

```
var days = {
    lunes: 1,
    martes: 2,
    miercoles: 3,
    jueves: 4,
    viernes: 5,
    sábado: 6,
    domingo: 7
};
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
function checkDay(day){
    return days[day];
}

checkDay("lunes");
```

**Edit:**  I misunderstood the question.

```
function checkDay(){
  var days = ['Lunes','Martes','Miercoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sábado','Domingo'];
  var today = new Date;
  return days[today.getDay() - 1];
}

console.log(checkDay());  //Returns Martes which is today, future readers
```

Comment: It could work if I put instead of "lunes" the getDay function to obtain the current day.